# Somewhat off-topic question about replacing glass top with something same thickness but less brittle. This is for a 49” x 69” vacuum press.

Tags: metal, glass

I have a cold-mount vacuum press which is basically a flexible mat bottom and a glass top that closes around material and then a vacuum pump sucks the air out, pulling the flexible bottom up against the top, smooshing whatever is in there. I use it to glue various things to various other things. Well I was using it to glue a paper thing to a wood thing and I broke the glass. It got destroyed in spectacular loud implosion fashion. The glass measures 49”x69”x1/4” thick. I do not want to replace it with glass though, because I want to continue to smoosh all sorts of things together and I will definitely break the glass again!

The material needs to be 1/4” thick or thinner, because of the hinges, although I *could* replace the hinges if I was *really* motivated.

I was looking at aluminum which I can get for about $250 for 5052 plate.

Anyone have ideas about rigid light material I could use? Preferably cheap - price is the only reason I’m asking the question instead of just buying the aluminum.

Comment: Why not acrylic plastic sheet?

Comment: @bib I’m concerned that the same forces that broke 1/4” glass will crack acrylic. I have no experience with it though.

Comment: lexan will not break. it can stop shotgun blasts. there are other even stronger materials, but they get pricey.